# Javascript SDK not returning page id, admin, liked when loaded in page tab

Tags: javascript, facebook

When logging in with FB.login the response.authResponse doesn't include the page property with the id, admin, liked.

However, if we load the page in PHP it does include it in the signed request (getSignedRequest).

I thought it use to work ok using javascript.

The problem is if you develop a primarily javascript app you then can't detect the page unless you use the server. Requiring a refresh after using the javascript login so the server can parse the signed request.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. Facebook only sends the page tab info to the server as part of the signed request get variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Requiring a refresh after using the javascript login so the server can parse the signed request.

Not necessarily a “refresh” – a AJAX request will do as well.

> Any ideas?

If a roundtrip to the server isn’t feasible in your situation, you could also parse the signed request client-side – for base64 decoding modern browsers know the method `window.atob`, and for older browsers you can grab a script to do it from the web. That would be just *decoding* the signed request, though, without actually *verifying* it. If you need to do that as well, you’ll have to go with the server-side approch, since that requires your app secret.

Comment: I've tried an ajax request to a php which parses the JS signed_request - it still doesn't contain the page or user data that the PHP signed_request does.

I can only assume that data isn't being sent to the JS SDK and is only sent to the PHP SDK.

Unless anyone else can test and confirm they are getting this data via the JS SDK alone?

Comment: Correct, this data is not send with the signed_request that JavaScript gets passed – because you can call FB.login from _anywhere_, so there is no (sensible) way of knowing whether you’re in a canvas/page tab, or somewhere else. So if you want the data that is only passed with the signed_request when entering a canvas/page tab app, you have to parse this data server-side on first page load – then you get the page id, liked etc. info. And it does not require a “round trip”, because it’s the first initial request to your app that’s happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the signed Request from using Javascript api you can do it with `FB.getLoginStatus()` to retrieve the signed_request. That is if the the user is logged into your app/website.If not you can call the FB.login method. i Tried this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', //change the appId to your appId
                    status: true, 
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    oauth: true});



               function updateButton(response) {

                 console.log(response); 

                 if(response.status == 'connected'){
                     //alert('Yes Connected');

                    console.log(response.authResponse.signedRequest);  
                    //This log can be seen through the firebug extention in console tab 
                 }
                 else{
                     alert('Not Connected');
                 }

                }

                // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
                FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);

            };

            (function() {
                var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                e.src = document.location.protocol 
                    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());



        </script>
```